# I can't figure out the reason for this error

Tags: go-ethereum, geth-debugging, poa, full-node, geth-clique

There are no problems with the nodes.
but i keep getting this warning
What exactly is the reason for this?

```
err="signed recently, must wait for others"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a clique (proof-of-authority) network that error might occur when the sealer nodes are not up. Remember that in a proof-of-authority network **the 51% of sealers must be up and running** and (of course) connected to the network.
What I can suggest you is:

- Make sure the 51% of the sealer nodes are up (if you have 2 sealers then make sure that both are running).
- Make sure that the sealres are connected: check if all the sealers have the same bootnode address.
- If you are running different nodes in the same computer/server make sure you assign different ports.
- Try simply stop and restart the whole network.

Answer (score 0):

Along with the above answer, ensure that your server's time is in sync with the other nodes or your rpc-only node. Since this is a POA system, you could access other node servers. A simple ssh time sync can be a handful: `sudo date --set="$(ssh <user>@<ipv4> 'date -u')"`